# How to make admin's actions hidden

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there a way in Windows Server 2008 SP2, to make Administrator user account's action "hidden".

By that I mean that any action s/he performs would not be logged anywhere. This includes registry, windows event log and any other kind of logs.

If so, where could I find these settings? My server is acting weird and I think it may have been hacked, but the hacker has disabled logging for his account somehow.

Comment: If the server has been hacked, what makes you believe that the tools are showing you an accurate picture?

Comment: Hmm, of course that makes sense. But before I make any drastic changes to the server I wish to play with the built-in settings first. The tools (executable) seem to be alright (hash-wise).

Comment: No way to hide everything to be honest. However hacking (not what people refer to as hacking) is very low level so would not be simply someone logging on as the administrator account and changing things that is more illegal access rather than hacking. Maybe if you explain some weird behavior we can help more?

Comment: If you are an Administrator, why hide an action, you can just delete the logs.  I am basically trying to say your asking the wrong question.

Comment: Nah, it's fine. I'll leave this question as-is and write a new one once I do some more investigation.